# Handling values from database in Adapter in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am retrieving data from the `database` in android in `Adapter class` and I want to make that values from the database to be specific. Because while I am scrolling up or down the effect that I want to disappear, So Here I need help in How to Handle data from the database `SQLite` in the `Adapter class`.

I have used an Expandable `ListView` instead of `RecyclerView` 
While Scrolling up or down the effect(Color For `TextView` in That `ExpandableListView` Group) disappeared

That's my Adapter Class:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_for_ayats, parent, false);
        //GET GROUP/SOurah item
        ListAyat listAyat = (ListAyat) getGroup(groupPosition);

        //SET Group Name
        arabicOne = convertView.findViewById(R.id.surah_ayat);
        englishOne = convertView.findViewById(R.id.english);

        SavedSourah savedSourah = new SavedSourah();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
                SavedSourahContract.GroceryEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                "sourahnumber="+savedSourah.getNumber(),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {

            int from = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2))-1;
            int to = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
            int revisedState = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4));
            int savedState = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5));

            fromList.add(from);
            toList.add(to);
            savedList.add(savedState);
            revisedList.add(revisedState);
        }

        if(fromList.size() > 0 && c < fromList.size() &&fromList.get(c) <= groupPosition && toList.get(c) >= groupPosition && savedList.get(c) == 1 )
        {
            arabicOne.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#447EE2"));

        }
        else{
            if(fromList.size() > 0 && c < fromList.size()&&fromList.get(c) <= groupPosition &&toList.get(c) >= groupPosition && revisedList.get(c) == 1)
            {
                arabicOne.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A82020"));

            }
            else{
                    arabicOne.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#905501"));
                    englishOne.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#64615D"));
                    c++;
                    Log.i("newcounteragain" , "here : " + c);
                    Log.i("newcounteragain" , "here : " + fromList.size());

            }

        }





        if(c > reading_sourahForAllList.fromList2.size()) {
            c = 0;
            fromList = new ArrayList<>();
            toList = new ArrayList<>();
            savedList = new ArrayList<>();
            revisedList = new ArrayList<>();
        }





        arabicOne.setText(listAyat.getAyah());
        englishOne.setText(listAyat.getAyahInEnglish());


        return convertView;
    }
```